# Count number of instances where a blank exists in one of 2 columns + r

Tags: r, dataframe, count, compare, missing-data

I need to test a dataframe for completion of records - for the records to be complete an entry must be made in both columns. In in the example `df` below you will see that 2 of the 9 entries contain blanks in one of the rows.

```
df <- data.frame(a = c(1,2,"",4,5,6,7,"",8,9),
                 b = c(9,5,2,7,5,"",3,"",6,8))
```

The desired output would be a count of `2 or 7` identifying the number of records that are complete or conversely incomplete. Instances where both are blanks would not be considered in the count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be `sum` of logical `matrix` - convert the 'df' to logical matrix (`df != ''`), get the `rowSums` and check whether the sum (`TRUE` -> 1 and `FALSE` -> 0) is equal to number of columns to return `n1` and subtract from the total number of rows to get `n2`

```
n1 <- sum(rowSums(df != '') == ncol(df))
n1
[1] 7
n2 <- nrow(df) - n1
# or if there are some other cases with `NA` etc
n2 <- sum(rowSums(df =='') == 1, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks @akrun! I know I didn't ask this in the question but will this account for instances where they are both blank? As i would not want to include them in the count, my actual dataset is like 10,000 rows...

Comment: @JohnConor can you try `n2 <- sum(rowSums(df =='') == 1, na.rm = TRUE)`